# Bitcoin Core `getaddressesbyaccount` method not found (-32601)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, address, public-key, bitcoin-cli

On macOS Mojave I have a full bitcoin node synced using `bitcoind`.

I want to get the public address of the default account (i.e. the empty string `""`).

So I run `bitcoin-cli getaddressesbyaccount ""` but I get:

```
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
```

Version of **bitcoind** is: Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.18.0.0-g2472733a24a9364e4c6233ccd04166a26a68cc65
Copyright (C) 2009-2019 The Bitcoin Core developers

And of **bitcoin-cli** is: Bitcoin Core RPC client version v0.18.0.0-g2472733a24a9364e4c6233ccd04166a26a68cc65

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account API has been deprecated for a while, and was completely removed in Bitcoin Core 0.18.0.

You should be using the new mutliwallet API, or handling account based labelling externally.